# how do I use the data in array in joomla list view as a link

Tags: joomla3.0

I have the following code " which is not quite correct" in a part of a list view in my component. For Joomla 3.4

```
<td style="text-align:center">
                <?php echo JDom::_('html.fly', array(
                    'dataKey' => 'link',
                    'dataObject' => $row,
                    'href' =>array($row->link),
                    'target' => '_blank'
                ));?>
```

I am trying to get the link from the field called link , but every thing I have tried either places the sites url before the link, does nothing or just goes back to the front page of the site. The link field contains a link to another website.

Can someone help me with this code snippet?